# Bad access when trying to clear and save different contexts

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need to perform periodic updates of the data I persist with `Core Data`. I get such data from asynchronous calls to REST services. To firstly retrieve all the data, I create a full core data stack in a private queue and then I do this:

```
- (void)updateDataFromServices
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
   self.dataUpdatePrivateContext = [MyCoreDataStackHelper getPrivateContext];

   if (self.dataUpdatePrivateContext != nil) {
       [self.dataUpdatePrivateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
           // Asynchronous operations
           [self callService1];
           [self callService2];
           [self callService3];
       }];
   }
}
```

In the callback of each service that is called, I check that the rest of services have already finished too, and if all have finished I call a method (`manageInfoUpdate`) to handle updates between the data I have in my main context (in main thread) and the data I now have in the private context (in the private queue):

```
- (void)manageInfoUpdate
{
   const char* UpdateInfoQueue = "com.comp.myapp.updateinfo";
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(UpdateInfoQueue, NULL);
   dispatch_async(queue,^{

    // Handle updates from private context:
    // Here I compare objects in the main context with the objects
    // in the private context and I delete objects from both
    // by calling:

    [mainContext deleteObject:object];
    [self.dataUpdatePrivateContext deleteObject:object];
    // This seems to work...

    // Save and clear private context
    [self saveContext:self.dataUpdatePrivateContext];
    [self clearContext:self.dataUpdatePrivateContext];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Re-fetch from main context to get
        // the updated data

        // Save main context
        [self saveContext:mainContext];

        // Notify end of updates
    });
});
}
```

I try to perform the `manageInfoUpdate` operations in another async thread. I'm getting `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` exceptions when trying to clear / save the contexts... Could somebody help me to find why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: managed object contexts are not thread safe. In particular your `manageInfoUpdate` method accesses mainContext and the dataUpdatePrivateContext both of which have been created in different threads.

Comment: @Rog Thanks. That's why I tried to save `mainContext` in main queue, but it does not work...

Comment: @Rog and on the other hand, why does comparing objects between contexts work, performing that in the same thread? I mean, I'm in a async queue comparing the objects of the mainContext (created in main thread) and the objects of the dataUpdatePrivateContext (created in private queue), and I get no error there...

Comment: You will get unexpected behaviour, it may work most of the time but it will fail eventually and these are bugs that are really hard to track. If you're targeting >iOS 8 I suggest you enable multi-threading assertions so the debugger will catch any attempt to cross threads with a context and throw an exception. See more details here http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Comment: @Rog Thanks, my base SDK is `iOS 7` but I'm testing in `iOS 9`... would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get an outright "error" for using Core Data in a multi-threaded environment incorrectly.  The app just will crash, sometimes.

To confirm you are using it correctly, turn on the debug flag `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` in your runtime arguments.  Then it will crash EVERY time you touch a MOC or MO from the wrong queue.

As it stands you code is not correct at all with regard to threading.  A MO that is created on one queue can only be accessed from that queue. Likewise, a MOC that is configured for the main queue must be accessed on the main queue and a MOC configured as a private queue must be accessed on **ITS** private queue.

Your "UpdateInfoQueue" is violating the threading rules completely.

Turn on the debug flag, correct the errors it shows you and your save issue will be corrected.

Comment: Thanks. I've enabled such flag and I'm seeing things that I don't understand, such the one I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774538/illegal-access-to-managed-object-context-why-com-apple-coredata-concurrencyde

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like once I have the managed objects in an array from whatever context they came, I can access them from whatever thread... is this correct? What is then exactly the illegal thing, to clear and save contexts in a different thread from the one that owns them?

Comment: No that is not correct.  The rule is simple.  A `NSManagedObjectContext` can only be touched on the queue that it is assigned to.  A `NSManagedObject` can only be accessed from the queue that the context belongs to that the object was retrieved from/inserted into.  Accessing a MO from another queue violates the thread confinement rule and can corrupt data, crash your app, cause deadlocks, etc.  That is why the debug flag exists.